# Webedit plugin won't work on Notepad++ 7.6.6 (x86) / Windows 8.1

Tags: notepad++, plugins

Somehow, my Webedit toolbar **disappeared** from Notepad++ but I really need it, especially the icons to place HTML tags around selected text.

I completely uninstalled/reinstalled Notepad++ to solve it but I'm not just getting there. The weird thing is that the **plugin manager** claims that Webedit is installed:

[image]

But still no toolbar. Besides, I don't see any trace of webedit in the **plugins menu**:
[image]

Could anybody please suggest **how to troubleshoot** this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [WebEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/WebEdit/) plugin is available in Notepad++ 32bit version only. If the plugin is not shown in Notepad++ Plugins Admin that can be added manually. Follow these steps:

1. Open Notepad++ installation folder. That should be in `ProgramFiles` or `ProgramFiles(x86)` folder.
2. Open plugins folder.
3. Create a `WebEdit` folder.
4. Download the plugin from this [SourceForge: npp-plugins](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/WebEdit/) project as a ZIP file.
5. Open the downloaded ZIP file and extract the files in previously created `WebEdit` folder.
6. Close any Notepad++ window and reopen it.